# Calculate $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2x-4y+5} + \sqrt{x^2+y^2-6x+8y+25}$, if $3x+2y-1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

As the title says, given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ where $3x+2y-1=0$ and $x \in [-1, 3]$, calculate $A = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+2x-4y+5} + \sqrt{x^2+y^2-6x+8y+25}$.

I tried using the given condition to reduce the complexity of the roots, but couldn't get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: make a geometrical interpretation and draw a picture:

$x^2+y^2+2x-4y+5=(x+1)^2 +(y-2)^2$ and consider the point $P(-1,2)$.
$x^2+y^2-6x+8y+25=(x-3)^2+(y+4)^2$ and consider the point $Q(3,-4)$.
Observe that $P$ and $Q$ are on the line $3x+2y-1=0$. 
Can you now see what $A$ means on the given interval?
The answer is here (mouse over) but try to find it yourself first:

> $2\sqrt{13}$

Answer (score 0):

$-1\le x\le3\iff-2\le x-1\le2$

WLOG  $x-1=2\cos u\iff y=-1-3\cos u$

$x^2+y^2-6x+8y+25=(x-3)^2+(y+4)^2=(2^2+3^2)(1-\cos u)^2$

$\implies\sqrt{x^2+y^2-6x+8y+25}=\sqrt{13}(1-\cos u)$ as $1-\cos u\ge0$

Can you take it from here?